Markdown-to-jsx stream custom markdown loading icon
I am using markdown-to-jsx in a progra that streams text from a GPT. In it, the GPT can make custom components in the styles of ''. However, the code to render something like this is:
<Markdown
 children={message.text}
 options={{
  overrides: {
    CarouselComponent: {
        component: CarouselComponent,
        props: { styles: styles },
    },
   },
  }}
 />

This means that the component only renders after everything has been written out. How do I have a component that renders a loading animation for my component using markdown-to-jsx while the component is being written but hasn't been fully written yet? Thank you!
